# jQuery .animate() not responding to millisecond settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, milliseconds

I'm using jQuery's .animate() to move a div around, and we need it to go slower.  It seems the slow, default, and fast settings have preset values of 200, 400, and 600 milliseconds, respectively, but the documentation states it can also be set to a specific amount.  I need the animation to take at least 1000 ms, possible more.  However, when setting "1000" or "1000ms", it seems to run at default speed.

Here's the function call I used:

```
  $("#welcome_popup").animate (
    {
    "top": "0px",
    "left": "590px",
    "right": "150px",
    "font-size": "13pt",
    "padding": "7px",
    "boxShadow": "6px 6px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)"
    }, "800");
```

I've tried it elsewhere and gotten the same result.  Here's an example from the web:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation2

In W3 School's own example, I can't seem to set the animate speed to anything other than those three values.  Has anyone else done this?

Comment: Don't put quotes around the time... `.animate({left:'100px'},2500);`

Comment: Show some code that you already tried

Comment: It works perfectly slower than the default 400 as stated here:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I don't understand why my question was voted down.  But, yes, it seems the quotes around the numbers are causing the problem.

Comment: I see that this was listed as off-topic, but I wasn't asking for "debugging help", as the notification states.  I was asking about the normal, expected behavior of a function and cross-checking if I was using it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options)

> duration (default: 400)   Type: Number or String A string or number
>   determining how long the animation will run.

When using ***Numbers*** in jQuery, they are not quotes as strings are.

**EXAMPLE**

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

[JSIFDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E87FQ/)